# How to find MongoDB documents in one collection not referenced by documents in another collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for an efficient way in MonogDB to determine, which documents in one collection are not referenced by documents in another collection.

The database comprises two collections, `inventory` and `tags`, where some (not all) documents in `inventory` reference one of the `tags` documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8df3c02e197074f39f61ea"), 
    "tag" : ObjectId("5e89a1af96d5d8b30aead768"), 
    "ean" : "5707196199178", 
    "location" : "shelf 1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8df211727079cdc24e20e1"), 
    "ean" : "5707196199178", 
    "location" : "shelf 1"
}
```

The 'tags' documents are without any reference to documents in `inventory`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d174fc63ce5b0ca80b89a"), 
    "nfc" : { "id" : "04:5f:ae:f2:c2:66:81" }, 
    "barcode" : { "code" : "29300310", "type" : "EAN8" }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e89a1af96d5d8b30aead768"), 
    "nfc" : { "id" : "04:48:af:f2:c2:66:80" }, 
    "barcode" : { "code" : "29300716", "type" : "EAN8" }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d1756c63ce5b0ca80b89c"), 
    "nfc" : { "id" : "04:02:ae:f2:c2:66:81" }, 
    "barcode" : { "code" : "29300648", "type" : "EAN8" }
}
```

Since not all documents in `tags` are used in `inventory` documents, I cannot simply have them as sub-documents.

Now I need to determine, which of the `tags` documents are **not** referenced by any `inventory` document. I would prefer not to have to maintain back references from `tags` to `inventory` to not risk inconsistencies (unless this can be done automatically by MongoDB?).

I'm very new to MongoDB, and from I've learned so far I'm under the impression that a view is probably what I need. But I seem to lack the proper search terms to find examples that help me understand enough to proceed. Maybe I need something different, here I'm hoping for your input to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to perform MongoDB aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator that allows two collections to be joined.

If there are "`tags` documents are not referenced by any `inventory` document", `join` field would be an empty array.

In the next step, we filter empty arrays with `$size` operator.

Try the query below:

```
db.tags.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "inventory",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "tag",
      as: "join"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "join": {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      join: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[`tags` not referenced](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zCThZpUB6Co) | [`inventory` not referenced](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oLzc-wfM2eG)

Comment: Thank you for this perfect solution! And for the links to the mongoplayground, just what I needed without knowing it yet.

Comment: How do you add a match condition to pull the ones where there was a match? I actually need the opposite to this